# Set of non linear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

Given

$\begin {align} x&=(1-x)y\\x&=(1-x)(1-y)z\\1&=(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)+x+(1-x)y+(1-x)(1-y)z\end{align}$

I end up solving 1=1. I don't think there is anything wrong with my working. Is there something about this set of equations that makes it unsolvable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third "equation" is in fact an algebraic identity, valid for $\,\forall x,y,z\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin {align}
1 &=(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)+x+(1-x)y+(1-x)(1-y)z \\
 &= (1-x)(1-y) - \cancel{(1-x)(1-y)z} + x + (1-x)y + \cancel{(1-x)(1-y)z} \\
 &= (1- \cancel{x} - \bcancel{y} + \xcancel{xy}) + \cancel{x} + (\bcancel{y} - \xcancel{xy}) \\
 &= 1
\end{align}
$$

This leaves you with two actual equations in three unknowns.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how $ (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)=(1-x)(1-y)-(1-x)(1-y)z $

Comment: @matt That's by distributivity $\,a(1-z)=a-az\,$ for $\,a=(1-x)(1-y)\,$.